# File copy from shared source folder to local destination folder using Apache FileUtils failed

Tags: java, apache, fileutils

I am trying to copy a file which is at remote machine shared folder using following code.

```
myMethod (String paramUrl) {    //URL of the folder shared on Remote machine
    logger.info("paramUrl="+paramUrl);
    URL url = new URL(paramUrl);
    logger.info("Source file address="+url.getFile());
    File inFile = new File(url.getFile());                      
    String destFileName = "D://LOCAL_FOLDER+"//"+xyz.xml;
    logger.info("destFileName="+destFileName);                      
    File destFile = new File(destFileName);                     
    FileUtils.copyFile(inFile, destFile);
}
```

**::::output is:::::::**

```
paramUrl=file:////10.0.0.3//SHARED_FOLDER//xyz.xml
Source file address=////10.0.0.3//SHARED_FOLDER//xyz.xml
destFileName=D:/LOCAL_FOLDER//xyz.xml
java.io.FileNotFoundException: Source '\\10.0.0.3\SHARED_FOLDER\xyz.xml' does not exist
    at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.copyFile(FileUtils.java:637)
```

**Note:**

*If I try to access the URL "\\10.0.0.3\SHARED_FOLDER" it works fine using RUN (in Windows). Folder shared with read/write permission for everyone.*

*Also If I share local-folder and tried to access from same machine using URL "////localhost//LOCAL_SHARED_FOLDER/xyz.xml" my code works fine.*

But I do not know, why it is not working for remote-machine ip-address,Please guys help me why it is not working

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**:
leave out the "file://" part. If you address the file as `paramUrl=//10.0.0.3/SHARED_FOLDER/xyz.xml`, the copy operation should work.

*old:*

If you mount `\\\10.0.0.3\SHARED_FOLDER` to a local drive (e.g. X:), you can pass the parameter

```
paramUrl=X:\xyz.xml
```

and you can copy the file because it is behaves a local file.

If you cannot mount the remote drive in Windows as a local drive, have a look at http://jcifs.samba.org/. There's an Java API how to deal with smb/samba shares.

Comment: I also tried  mapping shared folder as local drive. in that case also i was getting same exception. but same code works fine with actual local folder. I have written this code to work for local-folder and Shared-Folder both.

Comment: One more thing is that url.getFile() will change the URL to "\\10.0.0.3\SHARED_FOLDER\xyz.xml"  and remove flie:// part as you can see in exception. Above code is able to move a file from local-folder to another local-folder, but it is surprising to me why it is not working with folder that is is there in mapped drive.

Comment: Yea, in this case skip the `new URL(paramUrl)` part, but directly use `new File(paramUrl)`. e.g. `new File("//10.0.0.3/SHARED_FOLDER/xyz.xml")`

Comment: No it was not working even for local-system I have tested that before. That time I was using  *new File("//Loca-IP-Address/LOCAL_SHARED_FOLDER/xyz.xml")* . One more thing why mapped-drive and local-drive behave differently.

Comment: works on my machine. BTW: do you run the code on a linux box?

Comment: no it is windows. Also I found one issue that when I run it as a windows Service it is not working. But from command line it works fine now.